# Java 8: Stream, NIO and Lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, nio

I have a file that contains multiple lines.
Each line can be converted into JSONObject.

Example lines,

```
{"name": "a", "age": 28}
{"name": "b", "age": 20}
{"name": "c", "age": 30}
```

I am reading this file using new IO

```
Files.lines(path)
```

I want to use stream and convert each line to JSONObject like,

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(line);
```

I am not getting how to do using stream and lambda. Is there any way?

Comment: what have you tried so far though?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `Stream#map`, example:

```
List<JSONObject> result;
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {    
        result = stream.map(line -> new JSONObject(line)) // or map(JSONObject::new)
                       .collect(Collectors.toList());       
} catch (IOException e) { /* handle exception */}
```

Comment: Please don't promulgate bad exception handling. Catching, printing, then ignoring exception (continue as-if no exception occurred) is a very bad coding practice. Don't show that anti-pattern to the newbies on here.

Comment: Or simply remove exception handling from sample code. The question is not about exception handling, so why "pollute" the sample with it? Perhaps the right solution is for method where code is to declare `throws`. Maybe it's to catch and handle it. Either way, it's out of scope for this code.

Comment: @Andreas while exception handling is not part of the question, for _completeness_ I have included the try with resources statement because it's a way for me to show to the OP "if you open a file or other resource, you should also be prepared to close it.".

Comment: Then say that in the answer. Adding `catch` clause has nothing to do with remembering to close the stream.